# Maven build failed for org.eclipse.equinox

Tags: maven

Couldn't find a version in [1.0.0-v20070606] to match range [1.0.0,2.0.0)
  org.eclipse.equinox:app:jar:null

```
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.xsd</groupId>
            <artifactId>edit</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0-v200706262000</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.emf</groupId>
            <artifactId>common</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>   

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.equinox</groupId>
        <artifactId>app</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-v20070606</version>
    </dependency>
```